# What is the difference between WhenPropertyChanged and ObservableForProperty

Tags: c#, reactiveui

```
public class Obj: ReactiveObject {
    public Obj() {
            this.WhenPropertyChanged(n => n.Prop)
                .Subscribe(o =>
                {
                    Foo();
                });

            this.ObservableForProperty(n => n.Prop)
                .Subscribe(o =>
                {
                    Foo2();
                });
    }
   
    private bool _prop;
    public bool Prop { get => _prop; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _prop, value); }

    public void Foo() {}
    public void Foo2() {}
}
```

Both of these methods return `IObservable<Obj, bool>`. Description of both methods says that they observer property changes, yet only second reacts for changes (`Foo2` is called).

What is difference between these methods and when they should be used? Documentation on `https://www.reactiveui.net/` seesm to be outdated.

Comment: Think WhenPropertyChanged comes from dynamic data. You'll likely want to use WhenAnyValue

Comment: https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-any/ is what you want to use. ObservableForProperty is used internally inside rxui.